# CMOS astable circuit

Tags: multisim, astable

I have made the following astable circuit in Multisim:

[image]

However, it didn't work (oscilloscope reads 0V as an output.)

I think the problem is because of VDD and GND pins which are hidden in Multisim.

Does anybody know how can I make them visible? If I have another mistake please tell me.

Comment: I'm faily sure that the 4009BD_15V part has an internal 15V supply and a connection to the ground node.  just use a regular ground.

Answer (score 0):

you need a resistor between the capacitor and the input to prevent the protection diodes on the input from taking too much current.

[image]

slightly edited image from CD4060 data sheet.